# Keras sequence-to-sequence encoder-decoder part-of-speech tagging example with attention mechanism

Tags: deep-learning, keras, encoder, decoder, pos-tagger

I have a sequence of indexed words w_1, ..., w_n. Since I'm new to deep learning, I am looking for a simple implementation of a seq2seq pos tagging model in Keras which uses attention mechanism and produces a sequence of POS tags t_1, ..., t_n out of my word sequence.

To be specific, I don't know how to gather the outputs of LSTM hidden layers of the encoder (since they are TimeDistributed) and how to feed the decoder LSTM layer for each timestamp with the outputs of time "t-1" for generating the output "t".

The model I'm thinking about is looking like the one in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473.

Comment: You can get the full sequence of recurrent layers by passing them the `return_sequences=True` initialization parameter if that is your problem.

Comment: Does that mean that I will have access to the outputs of all layers once the output in the last node is computed (I will need to access the vector of h_0 to h_n in the attention layer)

Comment: My other problem is that I don't know whether I need a Sequential or a Graph container to produce the encoded vector of hidden states + input in attention layer, does `return_sequences=True` work in either or just a Graph one ?

Comment: There is no `Graph` model anymore. Please update your Keras and read the documentation. All your questions are answered there.

Comment: I remember I read about `Graph` in the documentation of the recent version which is currently available at http://keras.io/layers/containers/

Comment: It is deprecated. [Read the docs](http://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue will help you, though there is no attention mechanism. 
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2654

The code included in the issue is as follows.

```
    B = self.igor.batch_size
    R = self.igor.rnn_size
    S = self.igor.max_sequence_len
    V = self.igor.vocab_size
    E = self.igor.embedding_size
    emb_W = self.igor.embeddings.astype(theano.config.floatX)

    ## dropout parameters
    p_emb = self.igor.p_emb_dropout
    p_W = self.igor.p_W_dropout
    p_U = self.igor.p_U_dropout
    p_dense = self.igor.p_dense_dropout
    w_decay = self.igor.weight_decay



    M = Sequential()
    M.add(Embedding(V, E, batch_input_shape=(B,S), 
                    W_regularizer=l2(w_decay),
                    weights=[emb_W], mask_zero=True, dropout=p_emb))

    #for i in range(self.igor.num_lstms):
    M.add(LSTM(R, return_sequences=True, dropout_W=p_W, dropout_U=p_U, 
                  U_regularizer=l2(w_decay), W_regularizer=l2(w_decay)))

    M.add(Dropout(p_dense))

    M.add(LSTM(R*int(1/p_dense), return_sequences=True, dropout_W=p_W, dropout_U=p_U))

    M.add(Dropout(p_dense))

    M.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(V, activation='softmax', 
                                W_regularizer=l2(w_decay), b_regularizer=l2(w_decay))))



    print("compiling")
    optimizer = Adam(self.igor.LR, clipnorm=self.igor.max_grad_norm, 
                                   clipvalue=5.0)
    #optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.5, decay=0.0, nesterov=True)
    M.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, 
                                               metrics=['accuracy', 'perplexity'])
    print("compiled")
    self.model = M
```